# Display value in asset table if asset has completed all corresponding goals in goal table

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I have two tables: `AssetInfo_T` and `GoalInfo_T`. These tables are structured as a one-to-many relationship where an asset can have up to 10 goals with 10 subgoals each.

My `AssetInfo_T` table has the following fields:

- Asset
- Goal1
- Goal2
- etc.

The `GoalInfo_T` table has the following:

- AssetID
- Goal
- SubGoal
- Complete

Containing, for example:

[image]

What I need is to populate the corresponding goal in the `AssetInfo_T` with:

- `True` if the goal has been completed.
- `I/W` if the goal is in work.
- `False` if the goal has not been started.

A goal is complete if all subgoals are complete.

I have tried Excel-style code as my first attempt at this database was in Excel and my needs outweighed Excel's capabilities.

The way I went about it in Excel is the following:

1. Create complex two dimensional loop to create an array to determine if subgoals are complete.
2. Store value of `True`, `I/W`, or `False`.
3. Find Asset in `AssetInfo_T`.
4. Establish range of record and find cross section of goal and asset.
5. Using stored value, place value in cross section.

Again, this worked just fine in Excel. I am unaware of any way to use offset, for each loops, do loops, etc. in Access.

Again, my end product is to place (in `AssetInfo_T`) a value of `true` if all sub goals (in `GoalInfo_T`) under a particular goal is completed, an `I/W` if some subgoals are completed, and a `false` if no subgoals are completed.

Comment: Display sounds misleading. It sounds like you want to **write** a value to the db everytime a record is updated **if** both goals are completed. Look into/poke around with Data Macros (Assuming this is the newer format of Access DB files .accdb) https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-a-data-macro-b1b94bca-4f17-47ad-a66d-f296ef834200

Comment: AssetInfo_T does not appear to be normalized structure. Why duplicate data into 2 tables? An asset overall status can be calculated from the dependent goal records. In Access, code would open and manipulate recordset objects. Or UPDATE query can use DLookup() expression to pull value from another table.

Comment: Unfortunately none of my tables are of normal structure. All assets have been preloaded with the associated pertinent info. The user will then fill in metrics and goal completion status via forms. The current goal for an asset will eventually be passed to dashboard labels and will drive queries for reports. I do like the idea of using Data Macros as Pants suggested. When the user completes a sub goal, I could have it populate a field with the Y as shown above and then do the calculations through a query via percentage of completion thus eliminating the AssetInfo_T